# How do I find Size of Note Object in Salesforce Using API

Tags: notes

[image]

Note object doesn't have any property which can give it's size while using SOQL Query. Is there a way, I can calculate the size of Note using API.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have Size field on the Note object . We have the Size field on the Attachment object only as per the below [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.notes_fields.htm&language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5). As there is not field on the object you will not be able to query it.